# How to get numpy data to match

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I Have a text file where the first index is the index, second to the end of the text file is the cluster coordinates. I like to be able to query on the index. When I split into partitions like this.

```
     npdata_partitions = np.array_split(npdata, 5)
        first_partition = npdata_partitions[0]
        inital_kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=full_clusters, random_state =42).fit(first_partition[:,2:])
```

I can easily apply `kmeans` and get a good result (while keeping track of the the index). However, when I want the unsplit version, so I can look at any index that's in a list for the unsplit version to use `kmeans`.

```
    npdata = np.array([np.array(line.strip().split(','), dtype=np.float64) for line in open(input_datapath)]) #splitting the file one by 1 
# applying a list of indexes
new_dataframe = data_npdata[rs, 2:]
# applying k means
kmeans_rs = KMeans(n_clusters=five_times_k_clusters, random_state=42).fit(new_dataframe)
```

I end up getting really weird things that come out of the `npdata`,like this when I look at the cluster and indices by using `kmeans.n_cluster`s like this:

```
[array([21]), array([2]), array([3]), array([54]), array([49]), array([4]), array([5]), array([0]), array([51]), array([1]), array([39]), array([42]), array([10]), array([16])]
```

Long story short:
why is there such a huge difference in how `numpy` acts with a partition `npdata_partitions[0]` vs the actual `npdata`? How can I make them function the same?

Comment: the first solution is doing `.fit(npdata_partitions[0][:,2:])` whereas the second method is doing `.fit(data_npdata[rs, 2:])` I'm going to bet you are using completely different data here which is messing up everything. without having seen the data and more of your code, its impossible to say what you're doing wrong. As a side note, choose better names for your variables, calling everything `data` or `npdata` isn't very helpful.